# How to halt execution of current PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm writing some simple PHP to back up a microsite. In my controller, I have a quick security/sanity check

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $req)) { gohome(); }
```

I'd like to continue my the main code after this, but for aesthetics, I'd like to avoid putting the rest of it inside the `else` block. What's the best way around this? I can think of setting up a fairly simple wrapper to handle authentication and security logic, but I feel like I just missed a really simple solution in my training.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [die/exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function to end the script with (or without) an error.

Comment: This seems to work fine for my simple needs. I imagine that I would use something like what Phil Brown suggests below, using an Exception, and including the controller in a try block on slightly more sophisticated implementations.

Comment: @Steven Just note, `exit` stops the entire PHP process. No other code will be run from that point onwards. As your question alludes to this being part of a controller action in an MVC application, I doubt this is the desired behaviour.

Comment: Very good point, the "ideal" way in an MVC environment would probably incorporate exception handling in all controller, model, and view calls.

Answer (score 3):

You could

```
return gohome();
```

or

```
throw new Exception('Request may only contain letters');
```

Either will stop the execution of that particular script at that point.

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a function, you can usually just return early.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $req) or die("exit message here, if you'd like");
```

It's no better functionally than Xavier's but  I just like the syntax/idea of "do this or DIE"  :)   Also kind of makes me think of those old Nintendo games Skate Or Die and Ski Or Die.

Answer (score 1):

exit() is a pretty good way to terminate the current script...

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $req)) { gohome(); exit() }
```

I prefer to keep [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)/[die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) calls in the main flow. Or as Phil suggests, throw an [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and exit() somewhere lower in the stack

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply just write;

```
return;
```

The command will return program control to the calling script, so;

- If linear code in an included PHP file, the control will return to the script that invoked the running of that file.
- If in a function (or object method) the function will immediately return the argument if supplied, and `null` if not.
- It will not stop the running of the script completely (you need to use `exit` or `die` for that) unless there is no calling script.

So in your case;

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $req))
{
    gohome();
    return;
}
```

and the else block is not required since it will only continue the script if the condition returns false.